# how do I avoid using loops in this case or speed it up

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing

I was trying to match to data frames based on two columns date and latitude. Whenever the value of date and latitude is the closest to the values in the indicator data frame, I want to get the corresponding value of the indicator and assign it to the column of the other data frame.
here is my code but with over 1 million rows it takes a lot of time.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  cat("iter ",i,"\n")
  ik = which.min(abs(data$LAT[i]-indicator$Latitude))
  id = which.min(abs(data$DATE[i]-indicator$Date)) 
  ek = indicator %>%
    filter(Latitude==Latitude[ik], Date == Date[id])
  data$indicator[i] = ek$value[1]
}

dput(head(data, 20))
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17304, 17304, 17304, 17304, 
17304, 17304, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 
17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305, 17305), class = "Date"), 
    LAT = c(24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.208333085, 
    24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.208333085, 
    24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.208333085, 24.291666415, 24.291666415, 
    24.291666415, 24.291666415, 24.291666415, 24.291666415, 24.124999755, 
    24.124999755)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    DATE = structure(c(17304, 17305, 17305, 17305), class = "Date"), 
    LAT = c(24.208333085, 24.124999755, 24.208333085, 24.291666415
    ), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 19:20, 7:12, 13:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dput(head(indicator,20))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 
13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 
13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882, 13882), class = "Date"), 
    Latitude = c(20.875, 21.125, 21.375, 21.625, 21.875, 22.125, 
    22.375, 22.625, 22.875, 23.125, 23.375, 23.625, 23.875, 24.125, 
    24.375, 24.625, 24.875, 25.125, 25.375, 25.625), value = c(1199.2249, 
    1306.6454, 1382.2352, 1470.9645, 1687.3361, 1250.4304, 1176.1662, 
    1053.3858, 1116.7082, 1087.2385, 940.39806, 981.17173, 952.57968, 
    709.49989, 693.78443, 684.97014, 683.1336, 731.00416, 857.14393, 
    979.16759)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` and the same for `indicator`.

Comment: The data files are big, I just edited the question with dput.

Comment: Is it correct that you are taking each value in one data frame and look for its nearest neighbor in the other data frame? This has *O(n log n)* runtime with an appropriate data structure. In one dimension, you can use *binsearch*, in higher dimensions, you must use a kd-tree (there is an R library "kdtree", but that only supports 2D searches, AFAIK).

Comment: yes I try to find the nearest values for two columns.